# Tried inserting the values from DateTimePicker to database, but resulting into Invalid datetime format

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp

I am trying to insert the values from the DateTimePicker as it is not taking the values as I am beginner to this platform. So how do i convert the format and save into the database.

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $input = Request::all();
    $input['dob'] = Carbon::now();
    $input['app_date'] = Carbon::now();
    patient_user::create($input);
    return redirect('patient_user');
    $dob = Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-d');
    $app_date = Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-d');
    $dob->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $app_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    echo $dob->getTimestamp();
    echo $app_date->getTimestamp();

        DB::table("patient_users")->insert([
            "patient_firstname"=>$request->get("patient_firstname"),
            "patient_lastname"=>$request->get("patient_lastname"),
            "middle_name"=>$request->get("middle_name"),
            "gender"=>$request->get("gender"),
            "dob"=>(new DateTime($request->get('dobe')))->format('Y-m-d'),
            "pat_age"=>$request->get("pat_age"),
            "app_date"=>(new DateTime($request->get('app_date')))->format('Y-m-d'),
            "app_time"=>(new DateTime($request->get('app_time')))->format('H:i:s'),
            "branch_location"=>$request->get("branch_location")
        ]);
    }

Migration:
Schema::create('patient_users', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            //$table->increments('id');
            //$table->increments('patient_id');
            $table->string('patient_firstname');
            $table->string('patient_lastname');
            $table->string('middle_name');
            $table->boolean('gender');
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->increments('pat_age');
            $table->date('app_date');
            $table->dateTimeTz('app_time');
            $table->string('branch_location');
            $table->timestamps();
        }
```

Comment: PHP had a DateTime class with the method format read http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Can u just give a example of how to insert it as I tried the link which u have sent still getting the same error as Invalid format. @Raymond Nijland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you have some code at the beginning of the function that does not belong there. And the code after return will not execute.

Please replace your function with the following code and tell me how it works:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    DB::table("patient_users")->insert([
        "patient_firstname"=>$request->get("patient_firstname"),
        "patient_lastname"=>$request->get("patient_lastname"),
        "middle_name"=>$request->get("middle_name"),
        "gender"=>$request->get("gender"),
        "dob"=>(new DateTime($request->get('dobe')))->format('Y-m-d'),
        "pat_age"=>$request->get("pat_age"),
        "app_date"=>(new DateTime($request->get('app_date')))->format('Y-m-d'),
        "app_time"=>(new DateTime($request->get('app_time')))->format('H:i:s'),
        "branch_location"=>$request->get("branch_location")
    ]);
}
```

Comment: (new DateTime($_POST['app_date']))->format('Y-m-d') where should i add this exactly. In the controller right, because still i am getting the same error. @Badea Mihai Florin

Comment: Now the data is going into the database but the date field is showing null in the database. @Badea Mihai Florin

Comment: If you made any changes to the code, please update the first post, and then i will edit mine too. And tell me what date format does the datepicker return?

Comment: Now the code is working but in database date field is showing as NULL. @Badea Mihai Florin

Comment: What format does the datepicker have? If you print `$request->get('app_date')` what does it return?

Comment: Date format it is as data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" @Badea Mihai Florin

Comment: Hey thank you its working fine now. @Badea Mihai Florin :-)

Comment: Nice, i'm happy you got it working. You can leave a reply with the working code and mark it as solved, it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that the code after `return redirect('patient_user');` isn't run and that it is the line `patient_user::create($input);` which create your record? Also you should not use $_POST directly in Laravel, you can use `$request->get();` or values from your `$input` array

If you have set the date fields to be part of the $dates array in your model you can assign a unix timestamp to it directly and Carbon will handle the rest for you. How do your `patient_user` class look and does your DateTimePicker return Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse it with `Carbon::parse($date)`:

```
...

"dob" => Carbon::parse($_POST["dob"])->format('Y-m-d'),

...
```

If it's in any date format, `parse` method should figure it out.